# Null value and whitespace in Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex:

```
^(?P<port_name>[\w\d\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<description>[\S]+ ?[\S]+)\s+(?P<duplex>[\w]+)\s+
```

That I use on the following data:

```
>show interfaces status
Port      Description     Duplex Speed   Neg  Link   Flow  M  VLAN
                                              State  Ctrl
--------- --------------- ------ ------- ---- ------ ----- -- -------------------
Te1/0/1   CVH10 Mgt+Clstr Full   10000   Off  Up     On    T  (1),161-163
Te1/0/2   CVH10 VM 1      Full   10000   Off  Up     On    T  (1),11,101,110,
                                                              120,130,140,150,
                                                              160,170,180,190,
                                                              200,210,230,240,
                                                              250,666,999
Fo2/1/1                   N/A    N/A     N/A  Detach N/A
Te2/0/8                   Full   10000   Off  Down   Off   A  1
```

Which gives me this result (https://regex101.com):

[image]

I can't seem to figure out:

- How to match the description without also matching the duplex value of Full, because of it's spaces.
- How to match a value of null when there is no discription avalible as seen in the last two lines.

I'm starting to learn Regex and hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Hello SeanCedric please could you tell us what you want to match. What information to you want to extract or replace?

Comment: If the values for Duplex have a limited set of values, you can make the pattern a bit more specific `^(?P<port_name>[\w\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<description>(?!Full\b|N\/A\b)\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*?[^\S\r\n]+)?(?P<duplex>Full|N\/A)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<speed>\d+|N\/A)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/JDhn7d/1

Comment: thanks for the quick response! This is exactly how I want it thanks :) But now my question still remains is it possible to match something like 'Null' when there is no description avaiable like in the last two lines?

Comment: @SeanCedric The group for the description is optional, so using for example code, you can check if the group 3 (description) is present.

Comment: @The fourth bird Ah got it thank you so much!! I hope I'm allowed to bother you once more :) Now I'm using the following Regex: ^(?P<port_name>[\w\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<description>(?!Full\b|N\/A\b)\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*?)?\s+(?P<duplex>Full|N\/A)\b\s+(?P<speed>[\d\w\/]+)\s+(?P<neg>[\w\/]+)\s+(?P<link_state>[\w]+)\s+(?P<flow_control>[\w\/]+)\s+(?P<mode>[\w]+)\s+(?P<vlans>[\d(),-]+) Is it possible to also match the vlans on the next line when they are present and make the <mode> and <vlan> match optional so it also matches the line without vlans (like the second-last line)?

Comment: @SeanCedric Sure, the pattern will be slightly longer, see https://regex101.com/r/8uFycT/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assume that the columns are divided by at least 2 whitespace chars, so in that case you can make the pattern a bit more specific.

Note that `\w` also matches `\d`.

```
^(?P<port_name>[\w\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<description>(?!Full\b|N\/A\b)\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*?[^\S\r\n]+)?(?P<duplex>Full|N\/A)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<speed>\d+|N\/A)\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<port_name>[\w\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+` *port_name* match 1+ word chars or `-`
- `(?P<description>` *description*

  - `(?!Full\b|N\/A\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not Full or N/A directly to the right
  - `\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*?` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and optionally repeat 1+ spaces and 1+ non whitespace chars, as least as possible
  - `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ spaces (whitespace chars without a newline)
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `(?P<duplex>Full|N\/A)[^\S\r\n]+` *duplex* Match either Full or N/A
- `(?P<speed>\d+|N\/A)\b` *speed* Match either 1+ digits or N/A

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDhn7d/1).

To match all values including optional fields:

```
^(?P<port_name>[\w\/]+)[^\S\r\n]+(?P<description>(?!Full\b|N\/A\b)\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*?)?\s+(?P<duplex>Full|N\/A)\b\s+(?P<speed>[\d\w\/]+)\s+(?P<neg>[\w\/]+)\s+(?P<link_state>[\w]+)\s+(?P<flow_control>[\w\/]+)(?:(?P<mode>[^\S\r\n]+\w+)(?:[^\S\r\n]+(?P<vlans>[\d(),-]+(?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+[\d(),-]+)*))?)?
```

See another [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/8uFycT/1).